# Can I disable chat in Star Wars: Uprising?

Tags: star-wars-uprising

Basically I don't want to keep seeing the yellow exclamation mark every time someone posts in the general chat. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the forums there doesn't seem to be any way to stop global chat or even default to cartel chat. Interestingly this post came up in a search, though:
http://community.kabam.com/forums/showthread.php?413961-Turn-off-chat&styleid=-1
In the link (for a different game) somebody that is speaking as though they work at Kabam says you can request chat turned of by submitting an in-game help request. Might be worth a try in case they can do it in Uprising as well.